# Архитектура приложения android

Tags: android

Расскажите как правильно составлять архитектуру приложения?

Как его спроектировать?

С чего прежде всего нужно начать при разработке, как всё распределить и раставить по полочкам,где можно накидать макеты на каждый Activity?

Comment: Почитайте книги п.Дейтела и Б.Филлипса - там идет обучение на примере разработки реальных полноценных приложений, в том числе немало уделено внимания архитектуре и взаимодействию компонентов.

Comment: `С чего прежде всего нужно начать при разработке` -- с глубокого изучения Java (Шилдт/Эккель/Хорстманн, а потом Блох).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лично на своем опыте скажу. Ввиду наличия в начале пути только задумки и некоторых представлений по структуре веб-приложений, "архитектура `android`приложения" выглядела вполне себе "ясно". По мере изучения `java`, `android` приходилось эту самую архитектуру перессматривать. Плюс появляются идеи как улучшить приложение, что-то добавить, о чем даже не мог подумать в свое время.

Если сравнить ответы на вопрос "Как это сделать лучше?" в начале построения приложения, когда опыта мало и в конце, когда опыта уже побольше, но все равно так мало, то это будут очень разные ответы.

Итог.

1. Все ответы нужно искать исходя из поставленной задачи.
2. Чем больше опыта тем относительно прямолинейнее построение и реализация  архитектуры `android` приложения.
3. Накидывать макеты можно просто на бумаге. Макет лично мне подсказывает только направление.
4. Очень много библиотек, которые уже решают определенную задачу. Нужно только знать об их существовании и подключить.
5. ОЧЕНЬ помогает теория, а также `StackOverflow`, `Google` и радость от того, что что-то уже получается, работает.